# Как задать все уровни логирования logging python?

Tags: python, логирование

Как сохранять в файле не только 1 уровень логирования (в данном примере уровень INFO, т.к. это мы настроили в начале), а вообще все? Здесь уровень debug не записывается в файл. Как записать? Вместе с warning, error и critical?

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    filename='test.log',
    format='%(name)s %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO # как задать все уровень логирования, а не только INFO
)

for i in range(10):
    if i < 5:
        logging.info(i)
    else:
        logging.debug(i) # не записывается
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import logging
>>> print(logging.CRITICAL, logging.ERROR, logging.WARNING, logging.INFO, logging.DEBUG)
50 40 30 20 10
>>>
```

Вывод определяется условием больше-меньше. Если задать logging.DEBUG то выдаст всё с уровнем выше 10.